# Find out "ranking" of a value in SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, select

What is the easiest way with the highest performance, to determine the "rank" of an Integer value inside a MySQL database containing > 100.000 entries.

For example I have a Table "scores", with a column "value"

```
value 
50 
150 
10 
200 
180
```

The rank of 150 in this case would be 3, the rank of 200 would be 1, the rank of 10 would be 5, and so on...

What whoud the statement look like in php to determine the "rank" of a specific value?

Comment: Are you wanting a Rank (with ties) or a row number?  You can do this with user-defined variables.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many similar questions on StackOverflow that may offer what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about ties, I would do it like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS rank FROM scores WHERE value > $myScore
```

See it in action on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4662c9/16/0).

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.
What about the performance if this statement, since I am working with > 100.000 entries?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it looks correct to me... unless there are duplicated scores, but that's up to the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
select Value, RankNumber
from (
    select Value, @RankNumber:= @RankNumber +1 as RankNumber
    from table1, (select @RankNumber:=0) t
    order by Value desc
  ) A
where A.Value = 180
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4662c9/6)**
For performance concern, you can run a test, see if it can meet your bar.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know if you want the Row Number or the Rank (including ties), here is both options using `user-defined` variables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT value, 
      @rn:=@rn+1 RowNumber,
      @rank:=if((@value=value),@rank, @rn) rank,
      @value:=value
    FROM scores
      JOIN (SELECT @value:=-1, @rn:=0, @rank:=0) t
    ORDER BY value DESC
   ) t
WHERE value = 150
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/168c3/2)

This mirrors `RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` in other RDBMS.